# How can I remove Photos.app from Mac OSX El Capitan?

Tags: macos, photos.app

- Appzapper doesn't work
- Appcleaner doesn't work
- The typical Terminal Command i use doesn't work

Is the only way to doe this by disable SIP (System Integrity Protection)?

Answer (score -2):

Try AppZapper, i always use it but idk if it really delete Apple's apps

AppZapper can delete .app and also every configuration file that it have

EDIT: i've found [this](http://macpaw.com/how-to/how-to-uninstall-safari-on-mac-os-x), the guy in that tutorial is using CleanMyMac3 to do it. Hope it can help you

Comment: OP said AppZapper didn't work.

Comment: oh sorry... idk why i didn't see it... greetings